# Inheriting jQuery's Events Model

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing an SDK for a site API which depends on jQuery and I'd like to utilize jQuery's custom events model within the SDK.  How can I best inherit, wrap, or otherwise utilize jQuery's events without requiring an arbitrary DOM element to attach them to?

Current basic structure is below:

```
;(function($, global, undefined){

  function MySDK(opts){

  }

  MySDK.prototype.on = function(evt, fn){};
  MySDK.prototype.trigger = function(evt, data){};

  if(global.MySDK){
    throw new Error("MySDK has already been defined");
  }else{
    global.MySDK = MySDK;
  }
})(jQuery, typeof window === "undefined" ? this : window);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the events and listeners to the `window` object.

Example:

```
MySDK.prototype.trigger = function(evt, data) {
    $(window).trigger(evt, data);
};
```

If you're writing javascript for others to consume, I'd also strongly recommend you look into sandboxing your framework by running it inside of a src-less `iframe`.  All the better if each version SDK has it's own `iframe`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of using the window object, that should work perfectly.  I'd love to read more on the `iframe` sandboxing, would you have any recommended reading on that subject?  I've done some googling but the examples seem to focus on using eval to inject the code, which seems a bit hackish.

Comment: One of the developers from Disqus did a presentation on it.  Here's the slide deck.  Lots of example code to learn from.  http://www.slideshare.net/benvinegar/modern-iframe-programming-8281214